# Tkinter relief buttons when clicked python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

So, in Tkinter Buttons seem to have a relief property. This is defaulted to raised, and when the button is pressed it changes to sunken. I made my use relief=FLAT, but when I click this button it still is sunken. Is there a way to make it so that there is a different relief when clicked? Would it involve changing the border color?

```
Button(text=day, width=2,
       relief=FLAT, activebackground = self.color_clicked,
       background = self.today_color)
```

This looks flat, but when I click on it it changes to sunken (obviously it changes back to flat when I let go, however).

Comment: Please add an example block of code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Try `overrelief = ...`. `help(Button)` shows that to me.

Comment: @User overrelief is when I hover over the button, and is defaulted to the relief value. I want it to stay flat when it is pressed.

Comment: If you don't want the default behavior of a button, have you considered using a Label? You can easily create your own bindings to make it function like a button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tie a mouse-click to a function that enforces the relief of the button to keep it flat, otherwise the mouse-click will use its default action on click: making the button sunken.

```
def keep_flat(event):       # on click,
    if event.widget is btn: # if the click came from the button
        event.widget.config(relief=FLAT) # enforce an option

def callback():
    print('button clicked')

root = Tk()

btn = Button(root, text='click', relief=FLAT, command=callback)
btn.pack()

root.bind('<Button-1>', keep_flat) # bind the application to left mouse click

mainloop()
```

Another option is to bind the button-click to the string "break", which prevents any typical event handlers from kicking off (including the button's `command` option):

```
btn.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: 'break')
```

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Answer (score 6):

Setting `-borderwidth` `(-bd)` to `0` worked for me. The button text keeps moving down showing the button is being pressed, but sunken border doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Binding the mouse-click function is not the correct solution because the configuration code is executed after the button-down relief is displayed. Bryan's suggestion to use a label seems to be the only way to accomplish this simply.